# 3 wire receptacles in a 2 wire system

Tags: wiring

Just purchased home has 3 wire receptacles in 2 wire system which the lower of the two plug ins are controlled by a wall switch. There are 6 of these on one room.  How does a GFCI replacement receptacle in each box work with that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "How does a GFCI replacement receptacle in each box work with that?"

Comment: Poorly worded question. Tester101 covered it below.  I also considered an AFCI at the box, but I found out the breaker is on an old sub-panel (Turnbull Electric out of Conn.) that will not accept the new breakers.  Probably the best answer is to replace them with the two prong receptacles and let it go at that.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't install a GFCI receptacle in each receptacle location, you'd install a single GFCI device at the "beginning" of the circuit. This GFCI device could even be a GFCI breaker, or a GFCI device that doesn't have receptacles on it.

If you have split receptacles now (top always hot, bottom switched), you won't be able to simply replace them with a GFCI receptacle.  GFCI receptacles do not allow you to split the receptacles, so they will not work in your situation.